# copying files from one directory to another

Tags: powershell, directory, copy

I am trying to move the album art from my library (stored as albumart.jpg) from my PC to my phone. All the music on my phone is in FLAC format, however, to conserve space I have converted it to MP3 for use on the phone. Rather than copying every album art over manually, I thought there might be a way this can be automated in powershell.

the structure is d:\music\library\%artist%\%album% on my PC and on my phone it needs to be e:\media\music\%artist%\%album%.

I know I have to filter the results with a **Get-ChildItem d:\music\library -recurse *.jpg** and then I believe I need some sort of crazy ForEach that appends \%artist%\%album%\ to a specified directory.

Is something like this feasible or will it have to be done manually.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-replace` will do the magic.

```
ls "D:\Music\Library" -r -i *.jpg | % {cp -force $_ ($_ -replace "D:\\Music\\Library", "D:\\Music\\mp3")}
```

(If you need to establish the directory structure simultaneously, add `-force` switch to `cp` command.)

Comment: Hey Grapeot, I'm getting "InvalidOperation: (D:\Music\Library:String) [], RuntimeException".  Script I ran was **ls "D:\Music\Library" -r -i *.jpg | % {cp -force $_ ($_ -replace "D:\Music\Library", "D:\Music\mp3")}**. This is probably an easy fix but I'm not too familiar with powershell, technet articles didn't help me :(

Comment: This is weird... Maybe you can try to put the `-force` switch to the end after the parentheses? If the error still exists, could you please provide the whole error message especially location info like `At line:1 char:3`?

Comment: Invalid regular expression pattern: D:\Music\Library.
At line:1 char:65  
+ ls 'D:\Music\Library' -r -i *.jpg | % {cp -force $_ ($_ -replace <<<<  'D:\Music\Library','D:\Music\mp3')}  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (D:\Music\Library:String) [], RuntimeException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression

Comment: I see the problem. This is because "\" is for escape characters in regular expressions, therefore we should use "\\" for "\" in the path. The revised command should be `ls "D:\Music\Library" -r -i *.jpg | % {cp -force $_ ($_ -replace "D:\\Music\\Library", "D:\\Music\\mp3")}`.

Comment: D'OH >< ... I should have seen that! Thank you so much for the help this is pretty cool.